# Why MS Word 2010 always on top of other applications & how to stop it ?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

MS word 10 is always appearing on top of other applications in my windows 7x86 PC, Its bothering, how to stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the program CCleaner, in the cleaner tab under Advanced, check off the Windows/Size location box and run the cleaner.

Uncheck everything else if thats the only thing you want to "clean", but sometimes its good to check off all those boxes and run the cleaner now and then.

Comment: Sure that it helps? Or is it just a joke? :)

Comment: what the heck its working cool man.

Comment: duDE, I know it kinda sounds like a joke haha, but I've actually used this a few times for users when they have some oddball issues with window sizing and location! 
Glad it worked!